# Why is this custom formula conditional formatting rule triggering wrongly?

Tags: google-sheets

In this (partially redacted) sheet I want to set rules based on the Q column:
[image]

Q is date-formatted but clearly is *not* blank, so why is the formatting being applied? I've tried other rules like exact text-matching and they don't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you need is `=ISBLANK($Q2)`

By using the `$` sign in front of `Q2` you lock it and this way you get the conditional formatting applied on the whole range of row on the selected cells.

Comment: Did you check the answer? Is this what you were looking for? If not let us know.